# django DRF custom permissions: view-level permissions for detail views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im unsure about how to deal with permissions in detail views (such as `api/teams/<int:pk>`).
Suppose I have a custom permission class in place that should allow access if the requesting user is in the queried team.

something along the lines of:

```py
class IsInTeam(BasePermission):
  def has_permission(self, request, view):
    # should I implement this at all?

  def has_object_permission(self, request, view, team):
    return team.hasMember(request.user)
```

Since `has_object_permission` is called anyway (because "stock" views check the permissions upon calling `get_object` according to the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)):

> **Note**: The instance-level `has_object_permission` method will only be called if the view-level `has_permission` checks have already passed. Also note that in order for the instance-level checks to run, the view code should explicitly call `.check_object_permissions(request, obj)`. If you are using the generic views then this will be handled for you by default.

Now, according to this, `has_object_permission` will only be checked if `has_permission` has returned `True`. While this makes sense, one could argue that since this view is strictly based upon `CRUD` operations on a specific object denoted by `pk`, all necessary checks could be performed within the `has_permission` method.

**The question is**: Would this be bad practice? If so, why? The only reason I can come up with, is, that within `has_permission` one would have to check if the object even exists. This would be somewhat confusing, since permission checks should not have to check if the object exists.

Comment: I think You should use two permission classes - "IsAuthenticated" (Basic drf permission class) and "IsInTeam" class. In this configuration IsAuthenticated will be called first, so you will be sure that request.user != None, in next step IsInTeam has_object_permission will check that request.user is in team. You don't need to override has_permission method because it returns True by default (from super class). So after all... your permission class should override only has_object_permission method..... 3 lines of code :)

Comment: I know that I should use "IsAuthenticated". I left it out for the sake of simplicity. The question is... Why should i _not_ check if the user has permissions in 'has_permsission', when the entire view is bound to one specific object?

Comment: In my opinion (in most cases) has_permission method should only check GET/POST (list and create), and has_object_permission GET, PUT, DELETE (retrieve, update, delete) because it depends on get_object method and this is native GenericViewSet behaviour. So for the sake of simplicity, permission classes should be reusable for many cases/viewsets where these viewsets can be just ModelViewSets - and it will behave with these permission classes as expected.

Comment: I agree with you. So has_permission should only perform an overall check if the user is permitted, regardless of the specific item he is requesting, because this will be checked by has_object_permission anyway, right?

Comment: Right, has_permission can check for example if the user is admin if viewset needs admin permission.